# how to generate surround sound effect in html5

Tags: html, audio, webgl, three.js

Here is the problem statement...

I am creating a scene using WebGL(THREE.js).
I have different objects around me creating different sounds.
Now I want to produce surround sound according to their position.

So if an object is at my right side, then sound from that object should come from right speaker and so on..

Is this possible in HTML5(any browser)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AlteredQualia did a test with that.

http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_city.html (Chrome only)

Press `m` to disable the music, and `n` to enable the helicopter spatial sound.

Comment: FYI this demo is not true surround sound. My destination.maxChannelCount is 8 but my destination.channelCount is only 2. I am in Chrome 55. I am not sure if Chrome even supports destination output beyond 2 channels.

Comment: Maybe if your app sets the channelCount > 2 (if the max is > 2) and then produces sound in more than 2 channels, it would be true surround sound.